# Is there a way to change the Lock Screen without using PC Settings?

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen

I want to know if there is a way to change the Lock Screen in Windows 8 without using the default PC Setting way. Maybe a value in the registry or something?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the PC settings page? That's what it's for...

Comment: @Matthew I guess this could be useful for, say, domain administrators who need to set a lock screen for a large number of computers - where using a script to modify registry values is easy (and easy to lock to a set value/restore on login) but changing via the app would require manually going to each computer. They could also want to set up a script to change the image depending on time of day, etc.

Comment: @Bob: If that's his reason, maybe the title should be changed to "How can I programmatically change the lock screen". That's why I'm asking, to get a better idea of the problem he is trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 8 Apps can ask for permission to change the lock screen. One such app is called [Bing My Lockscreen](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-us/app/bing-my-lockscreen/7e1f890f-8960-43e5-a258-58ba3eeb1163) and pulls down images from Bing's background pictures library. This doesn't let you set a specific image, but gives you some choices to choose from.

If you need a way to this programatically yourself, you could write your own app for it. There is documentation on MSDN for [Lock Screen Personalization](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Personalization-App-sample-9ebfe147).

Alternatively, you can manually edit the lockscreen background image. It appears that this is stored per-user in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\LockScreen_x`, where `x` starts at A and increments as you add more options. Details related to this are stored in the registry under the following registry key, and are rather cryptic.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen
```

Update: I tried messing around with the above registry settings, and was unable to change anything. I actually managed to break the lock screen by deleting an entry, so... don't try that at home!

Some folks in [this TechNet forum thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/a8db890c-204f-404a-bf74-3aa4c895b183) were able to automate this by writing a script to overwrite the default backgrounds, which are cached in a hidden folder. Merely changing the folders mentioned above doesn't work. Depending on why you need to do this, there may be a solution in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing the picture in C:\Windows\Web\Screen with your picture to see if its works. It must be called `img100.jpg`