# Change lock screen daily using chosen folder of pictures

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

I would like my lock screen to update daily and cycle (systematically or randomly) through the pictures in a specified folder. My first thought was to lose the slideshow animations and increase the display time, but that doesn't seem to be possible. I haven't been able to find an app that can do what I want and I'm not sure I'm comfortable enough with Windows 10 yet to write my own using the information [from this question](https://superuser.com/questions/496685/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-lock-screen-without-using-pc-settings).

Does an app/code of sort already exist or am I on my own?

Comment: i couldnt test it, i dont use 8-10 yet, but following this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8db890c-204f-404a-bf74-3aa4c895b183/cant-customize-lock-or-logon-screen-backgrounds?forum=W8ITProPreRel 1/2 way down. one could make a "rename" batch, with a simple delete in it.  Basic, there is the original file items, then the cache which is specific res (and type and possibly size) , run a rename of a mass group of pics 001 002 . . . 030 and so on, either replace the cache direct, (exact size) or run renames on the originals , then delete the cache.  then answer your own question.

Comment: That sounds simple enough. Unfortunately, I'm back on Windows 7 due to an unresponsive Start Bar (a common problem, but none of the fixes worked for me). I'll probably just wait until I get a new computer instead of trying to upgrade again.